# VSCode API - Activation Events - Trigger only the first time or also after that?

Tags: vscode-extensions

In the [VSCode API Documentation - Activation Events](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events), we can read that:

> Your extension becomes activated when the Activation Event happens.

But it doesn't state if it happens only the first time the activation event happens or not.

For example, I'm using

```json
"activationEvents": [
    "workspaceContains:.git/HEAD"
]
```

, will the activation event be triggered only the first time it happens, or when `.git/HEAD` is deleted from the workspace and added again after, it will be triggered again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The activation occurs only once (the first time), no matter which or how many `activationEvents` you have defined. And, in the case you have added N possible `activationEvents`, you won't be able to know *which one* caused the extension to be activated.

If you need to *monitor* the recreation of files/folders (as you exemplified), to perform specific tasks and/or restart your extension state, you should create a file system watcher (`vscode.workspace.createFileSystemWatcher`) and take care of the extension's state according to your needs.